# Using minifyEnabled true to avoid multidex disables breakpoints - How to fix?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I am working an a existing Android app which includes the Dropbox SDK. The SDK includes a ton of new classes which makes it necessary to use `minifyEnabled true` in buildsettings to avoid multidex.

While this is no problem in my release config it has a major downside when debugging the app: Most of the breakpoint do not work any more.

Even if a breakpoint works and I would like to use the "step into" feature to step through the code it happens that this is not possible. Instead of stepping to the code, the call stack shows obfuscated instead of the real code:

```
a.c:111,f (com.my.app.a)
xb:106,f (com.my.app.a)
onCreate:62, MyApp (com.my.app.TheClass)
...
```

**So, I cannot set `minifyEnabled false`. Is there anything else I can do to still use my breakpoints?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to use ProGuard (`minifyEnabled true`) in order to prevent the app from requiring multidex, you can disable obfuscation and only use the shrinking feature of ProGuard (assuming that you dont use optimization e.g. when using `proguard-android.txt` as default config).

This should not create obfuscated stacktraces and allow you to debug the application.

**Edit:**

In order to disable obfuscation, just add

```
-dontobfuscate
```

to your configuration file.